# Update publish date programmatically in umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

How can I update the published date of a node programmatically in umbraco?

Comment: Are you asking how to actually publish a node, or just update the published date without publishing?

Comment: Or better off just publish the page in code that wili in turn update the published date.

Comment: Just how to update the published date of the node. The node is already published. I could successfully update the update date field in the cmsdocument table however i could not get that result to push through to the umbraco.config xml file

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the reason you're not just republishing the content, is because you want to set a specific date and not the current date?

You should be able to trigger a rebuild of the XML cache by using this function:
`umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache();`

This function is however marked obsolete in later version of umbraco so without having tested it I'm not sure if it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically update the date which a node was last edited using the [ContentService](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/management/services/contentservice).

You can usually access this service by using `ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService`.

```
var content = Services.ContentService.GetById(1060);

content.UpdateDate = new DateTime(2017, 07, 14, 17, 0, 0);

Services.ContentService.Save(content);
```

You can also update other properties on a node by using:

```
content.SetValue("propertyAlias", "value");
```

*Tested on Umbraco 7.6.1.*